# How to search data from a listview using textwatcher?

Tags: android, listview

I have created one listview in which data comes from a string array which is stored in `string.xml`.

I have one edittext and I want to search a particular data from my listview . My listview data contains like this 011 Delhi delhi... How can I do this?

Here is my code..

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

Resources res = getResources();
String[] a = res.getStringArray(R.array.states);
arrayList.add("" + a);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope the below code works for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;
    private EditText et;
    String listview_array[]={"123","TWO","Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "1234", "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800", "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};
    private ArrayList<String> array_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
    int textlength = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
        int x= lv.getHeaderViewsCount ();
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
            int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
            int start, int before, int count)
            {
                textlength = et.getText().length();
                array_sort.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < listview_array.length; i++)
                {
                    if (textlength <= listview_array[i].length())
                    {
                        if (et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        (String)
                        listview_array[i].subSequence(0,
                        textlength)))
                        {
                            array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. it works..but there is one problem my listview contains 011 Delhi delhi...if i write Delhi than it does not display wt to do fot that ?

Comment: To search delhi you have to type 011 D. It matches 011 then space then searches for anything that starts with D.

Comment: But what if i want to find a code for new delhi than how it is possible ?

Comment: write your own search criteria. Modify the if condition inside for loop. You can use regular expression and pattern matching to match part of string.

Comment: do you want your search criteria to match the code 011 or the city name Delhi?

Comment: listview item contains 01634 ABOHAR Punjab so if i write ABOHAR/01634 it display 01634 ABOHAR Punjab....can u give me the code ??

Comment: You mean to say if the listview contains 011 Delhi and you type D in EditText then listview display must be 011 Delhi. Is this what you want?

Comment: if(listview_array[i].toString().contains(et.getText().toString()))
{       array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
}.This should solve if you want it exactly as the above comment.

Comment: This helped me tremendously.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can search like this:

```
String text_to_search = editText.getText().toString();
for(String str : your_list) {
    if(str.equals(text_to_search) {
        //Do your operation
    }
}
```

If you want an index then you can use our traditional `for` loop.

Comment: is there any limit in array in string.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your Adapter.

```
public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase();
        picList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            picList.addAll(listpicOrigin);
        } else {
            for (Picture pic : listpicOrigin) {
                if (pic.getPicName().toLowerCase().contains(charText)) {
                    picList.add(pic);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

More detail you can make reference to [this tutorial](http://www.9android.net/adding-search-functionality-to-custom-listview/)