# SimpleAdapter Filter with EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, simpleadapter

I'm using an `EditText` to filter a `SimpleAdapter` with `SimpleAdapter.getFilter()`, but the result is filtered starting only from the first character but I need to filter it starting from anywhere on the string (for example, if my `list` is name1, name2, name 3. and i need to find name3 by typing only 3).

Here is the code I'm using

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

         adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);

    }
```

Comment: You will need to roll out your own adapter and override the `filter()` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881546/how-to-search-data-from-a-listview-using-textwatcher/12881577#12881577. check the answer in the link change the condition if(listview_array[i].toString().contains(et.getText().toString())) {  array_sort.add(listview_array[i]); }.

Comment: thanks, i resolved following your link :)

Comment: @user2416775 you want me add the solution here so that you can accept the same for clarity?